# Getting UserInfo information from a JWT token and using only JWK validation on Spring Boot OAuth2 autoconfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak

I'm creating a RESTful service that authenticates all incoming requests using the OAuth2 mechanism with an external Keycloak User Authentication Server (UAA).

The service acts as a Resource Server using the `@EnableResourceServer` with the following configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(0)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ResourceServerTokenServices resourceServerTokenServices;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(ResourceServerTokenServices resourceServerTokenServices) {
        this.resourceServerTokenServices = resourceServerTokenServices;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilterAfter(oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
    }

    private OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter() {
        OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter = new OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter();
        oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(oauthAuthenticationManager());
        oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.setStateless(false);

        return oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter;
    }

    private AuthenticationManager oauthAuthenticationManager() {
        OAuth2AuthenticationManager oAuth2AuthenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();
        oAuth2AuthenticationManager.setResourceId("country-microservice");
        oAuth2AuthenticationManager.setTokenServices(resourceServerTokenServices);
        oAuth2AuthenticationManager.setClientDetailsService(null);

        return oAuth2AuthenticationManager;
    }

}
```

I'm also using the following dependencies to include the Spring Security OAuth2:

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The users authenticate themselves on the UAA to obtain a JWT token that they must use to call the service that I'm creating. The JWT token itself contains the user information:

```
{ 

  ...

  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "user"
    ]
  },
  "scope": "profile email",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "Test Derp",
  "preferred_username": "user1",
  "given_name": "Test",
  "family_name": "Derp",
  "email": "test@test.com"
}
```

To avoid making another request to the UAA, the service uses the JWK to validate the incoming token. I'm setting the `security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri` property using the Keycloak's Certificate Endpoint:

```
security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri=http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

The problem is that Spring is not getting the user information that is found on the JWT token and fill it in the `Authentication` object.

I have the following controller to return the principal information:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/user", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping
    public Object getUser(Authentication authentication) {
        if (authentication != null) {
            return authentication.getPrincipal();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

The `Authentication` object is passed with **null** in the `getUser` function (with the JWK validation).

I've tried to use the following configuration to customize the `JWKTokenStore` with a `JWTAccessTokenConverter`, but it didn't work:

```java
@Configuration
public class JwkStoreConfig {

    private final ResourceServerProperties resource;

    @Autowired
    public JwkStoreConfig(ResourceServerProperties resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices jwkTokenServices(TokenStore jwkTokenStore) {
        DefaultTokenServices services = new DefaultTokenServices();
        services.setTokenStore(jwkTokenStore);
        return services;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore jwkTokenStore(JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter) {
        JwkTokenStore jwkTokenStore = new JwkTokenStore(this.resource.getJwk().getKeySetUri(), jwtAccessTokenConverter);
        return jwkTokenStore;
    }

}
```

The only solution that worked until now is to forget the usage of JWK and change the service to use the Keycloak's UserInfo to validate the incoming token, using the `security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri` property and delete JWK URI property:

```
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

With this property set, the `Authentication` object is passed to the controller with the user information, but this makes the service to request the UAA everytime it needs to validate the incoming tokens.

Any ideas?

Thank you.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for this is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server.html#boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server), although to me it's not entirely clear and at least with my setup it doesn't work as it expected.

My understanding is that these two properties should be used together:

```
security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-uri: http://localhost:9191/auth/realms/master
security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri: http://localhost:9191/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

That fails for me though, with a somewhat uninformative log message:

`Authentication request failed: error="invalid_token", error_description="Cannot convert access token to JSON"`

Debugging into Spring Security code a bit, it looks like if for what ever reason it could not internally resolve/create the public key for verifying the signature, it will give the error above.

This worked for me...

If you set the property `security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-value` to the actual public key then it does verify, as well as unpack the user info from the JWT, without needing to call back to(or configure) the user info endpoint. The down side to that is the public key has to be copied into code and updated everywhere if it changes.

Note the value of this property has to include `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n` at the start and `\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`.

E.g.

`security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-value: "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIB......\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"`

I haven't tried, but I'm pretty sure that would also work with actual line breaks in YAML with:

```
security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-value: |
  -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
  ...
  -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I *think* the reason why the fist set of properties don't work for my set up is because the key returned from the key-uri doesn't have these begin and end segments and Spring Security expects them to be there.

This probably doesn't answer your question directly, but hopefully still helpful. Spring security logging was quite sparse, and I found those properties to be really fiddly in how much they changed the behavior of things without useful much logging info indicating what's going on, even on TRACE level.